# groupby with multiple condition and operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a problem I want to groupby by and do some operation on a dataframe. The input dataframe is somethink like this:
[image: input Dataframe]

I want to groupby based on unique_id but if there are two observation i need two row in one unique id.  there could be any number of observation in 1 unique_ID

expected Output:

[image: output dataframe]

I have tried to make an count  and another columns out of It to help in groupby but i didn't work for me.

```
df["Count_ob"] = df.groupby("Unique_ID")["IF_car_history"].sum()
```

Help is appriciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Unique_id':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                   'Car_history':[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
                   'Value':[1000,1500,1000,1200,800,700,1300,1700],
                   'Ob_id':[0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4]})


df["Count_ob"] = df.Ob_id[::-1].cumsum()[::-1] # <=== this do the trick!!!
df["Count_ob"] = df["Count_ob"].max() - df["Count_ob"]

df = df.groupby("Count_ob")[["Unique_id","Car_history","Value","Ob_id"]].agg({'Unique_id':'max',
                                                                        'Car_history':'sum',
                                                                        'Value':'sum',
                                                                        'Ob_id':'sum'}).reset_index(drop=True)
df['Value'] = df.groupby('Unique_id')['Value'].cumsum().values
```

Comment: Hey, This did a trick for sure. thanks for your time. but when In result of unique ID 3 and ob_ID 4 i needed addition of all four rows @Marco

Comment: Can you put your output after marcos answer ?